# How to Add UserControl to UniformGrid in .cs

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls

EDIT: When I want to add VideoStream directrly to the grid by: `Grid.Children.Add(VideoStream);` IDE says that this is wrong argument.

I have a class:

```
 public partial class VideoStream : UserControl
```

And the `MainWindow` class I would like to add this `UserControl` to `UniformGrid` inserted in that Window:

```
<Window x:Class="HomeSecurity.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" WindowState="Maximized">

    <UniformGrid x:Name="Grid">
        <WindowsFormsHost x:Name="Host"></WindowsFormsHost>
    </UniformGrid>
</Window>
```

---

```
 public partial class MainWindow : Window {
        public MainWindow() {
            InitializeComponent();
            VideoStream VideoStream = new VideoStream();
          //  VideoStream.TopLevel = false; 
           // WindowsFormsHost Host = new WindowsFormsHost();
            try {
                Host.Child = VideoStream;
                Grid.Children.Add(Host); //THIS CAUSES THE EXCEPTION
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Console.WriteLine(e.StackTrace);
            }

        }
    }
```

But I get exception:

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in PresentationCore.dll
   w System.Windows.Media.VisualCollection.Add(Visual visual)
   w System.Windows.Controls.UIElementCollection.AddInternal(UIElement element)
   w System.Windows.Controls.UIElementCollection.Add(UIElement element)
   w HomeSecurity.MainWindow..ctor() w c:\Users\R\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\HomeSecurity\HomeSecurity\MainWindow.xaml.cs:wiersz 28
'HomeSecurity.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: HomeSecurity.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\UIAutomationProvider\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\UIAutomationProvider.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'HomeSecurity.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: HomeSecurity.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\UIAutomationTypes\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\UIAutomationTypes.dll'. Symbols loaded.
```

How to correctly add this `UserControl` to the `UniformGrid`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that in XAML only:

```
<Window x:Class="HomeSecurity.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:NamespaceWhereVideoStreamDeclared"
        Title="MainWindow" WindowState="Maximized">

    <UniformGrid x:Name="Grid">
        <WindowsFormsHost x:Name="Host">
            <local:VideoStream/>
        </WindowsFormsHost>
    </UniformGrid>
</Window>
```

Declare namespace `local` at root level and replace *NamespaceWhereVideoStreamDeclared* with actual namespace where VideStream is declared.

---

If you want to do that in code behind, you don't need to add Host to Grid since **Host is already child of Grid**.

```
Grid.Children.Add(Host); // Remove this line and you are good to go.
```

Comment: But when I want to let user decide how many this usercontrols he wants to see. how to do it without a C# code? There are no conditional instructions in XAML.

Comment: Good point, overlooked it. Thank you, but the problem is that now I see no user control in that grid. I mean no user control that I created is visible in this uniformGrid. When I changed `VideoStream` to derive from `Form` the content is visible, but I was told on stackoverflow that `VideoStream` should derive after `UserControl` not `Form`

Comment: No in case you want to add UserControl, you should add directly under `Grid` but only WinForm components can be added in `WindowsFormsHost`. If it needs to be hosted under `WindowsFormsHost`, it should derive from `Form` only.

Comment: Oh ok. so now I get to the problem in OP when I want to do not use `WindowsFormsHost` and add `VideoStream` directrly to the grid by: ` Grid.Children.Add(VideoStream);` IDE says that `VideoStream` is incorrect.

Comment: VideoStream deriving from `System.Windows.Controls.UserControl`. Right?

Comment: Derives from: `System.Windows.Forms.UserControl`.

Comment: WPF supports only controls deriving from `System.Windows.Controls.UserControl`.

Comment: Here is how this looked before, when the `VideoStream` derived from `Forn`. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20912025/argumentexception-occurs-when-inserting-form-containing-activex-control-into-win

Comment: I have no more problem with inserting Form in that grid, but when I want to use `UserControl` I start getting problems.

Comment: That problem is specific to `ActiveX` component because you already mentioned in it `The identical Form in WinForms application causes no problems. Removing Activex control from this Form removes the exception(in WPF).`

Comment: Simple thumb of rule is - If you are using WinForms, you can host via `WindowsFormsHost` but if want to add directly under `Grid`, it should be WPF component.

Comment: That was then. The problem with activex was solved by:`VideoStream.TopLevel = false;` but then `VideoStream` derived after `Form`. Now `VideoStream` derives from `UserControl` and that's the moment when current exception occurs. THANK YOU FOR YOUR PATIENCE.

Comment: Current exception occurs because you are adding `Host` again back to `Grid`. However as long as you are adding `VideoStream` to `Host`, it should work fine.

Comment: You are right. I did not see the UserControl because it was added on white background. But I do not know why the grey background of usercontrol was ignored. But this is topic of different question. THANK YOU.

Comment: You're welcome Yoda. Glad it worked finally for you. :)